# How to handle collision with ShapeRenderer in LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx, collision, shape-rendering

I'm trying to make a little game for Android with LibGDX and am having a hard time with collision detection.
So, I have two shapes :
The first one is a rectangle (the player) :

```
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.BLACK);
shapeRenderer.rect(position.x, position.y, width, height);
shapeRenderer.end();
```

The second one is the following, kind of a cage :

```
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.BLACK);
shapeRenderer.rect(0, 0, 50, Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
shapeRenderer.rect(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), 50);
shapeRenderer.rect(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()-50, 0, 50, Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
shapeRenderer.rect(0, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-50, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), 50);
shapeRenderer.end();
```

My question is :

How can I detect collision between these two objects ? The only way I know, how to detect collision is with the intersect method from the Rectangle class but I would like to make more complex shapes than rectangles.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: The more complex shape you are talking about is just made up of multiple smaller rectangles. Do you just want those, or even things like triangles, and other polygons?

Comment: No, I think I only want to use small rectangles in order to make bigger shapes. Should I then create a rectangle from the Rectangle class for each small rectangle I want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation `ShapeRenderer` isn't efficient and shouldn't be used intensively.

> Renders points, lines, rectangles, filled rectangles and boxes. This
>   class is not meant to be used for performance sensitive applications
>   but more oriented towards debugging.

A better approach might be to allocate a `Sprite` with a small white texture that you upscale to the appropriate size. Set tint and alpha with [setColor(..)](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html#setColor-com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color-) method.

For collision `getBoundingRectangle()` of Sprite return bounding axis aligned Rectangle, that will help you in collision.

You can manually create a texture by using pixmap.

```
public static Texture createBgTexture() {
    Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(1, 1, Format.RGBA8888);
    pixmap.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    pixmap.fill();
    Texture texture = new Texture(pixmap); // must be manually disposed
    pixmap.dispose();

    return texture;
}
```

For more complex shape use [Physics Body Editor](http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/projects/physics-body-editor/), that will return vertex point of your shape in readable file format, use that points and create [Polygon](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Polygon.html).

Libgdx having `Intersector` class, containing many static method for collision detection like `intersectPolygons(....)` and more.

---

On the other hand If you want a realistic collision detection, You can use box2d in your game. Inside box2d API there is a `ContactListener` interface that will tell you when two body collide.

Comment: Okay I leave ShapeRenderer haha ! Thank you very much for your help I'm gonna try what you told me !